# Trying to hide a section if a text field is changed, while a certain option is also selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a section that I'm working on hiding in different scenarios.

1. Option A is selected from Select Box
2. Quantity is updated via text field

It is working for #1, but not #2. I need to have it hide when the quantity is updated, and option A is selected. I have the following code, with no validation issues, but it isn't working and I don't know why.

```
$("#quantity").change(function(){
   if(document.getElementById('select-box').value == "MyOption") {
       $('#divtohide').hide();
  }
});
```

I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Can you share your HTML code please?

Comment: try `if (document.getElementById('select-box').options[document.getElemenById('select-box').selectedIndex].value == "MyOption")` -- or use jQuery's val(). Of course, that ugly line would be easier with a reference to the select actually saved...

Comment: `select` elements don't have a `value` attribute - you would need to get the selected option. Or use jQuery: `$("#select-box").val()` will get the selected option value.

Comment: Hah. Just beat you to it, @tymeJV. :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lhy19og/  What are you guys talking about?  Tested in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.  Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById('select-box').value` will not return the value of selcted option, instead since you're using jQuery your code could be simplified to :

```
$("#quantity").change(function(){
    if( $('#select-box').val() == "MyOption" ) 
    {
        $('#divtohide').hide();
    }
});
```

**NOTE :** I suggest the use of `input` event because it's more efficient when you track the user inputs :

```
$("#quantity").on('input', function(){
```